# Probability of a random variable - Wealth Model

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider a group of people. Each person has a certain wealth. At step

Let's split the group of people into two groups. The people are assigned to either group at random.

The total wealth of group 1 is $m_1$. The total wealth of group two is $m_2$. The total wealth of the overall group is $m=m_1+m_2$

We say that $P(m)=P(m_1)P(m_2)$. **Why is this so?**

This question is based on an excerpt from a paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0001432.pdf
)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the probability density $P(m)$ I would probably rather look at $\mathbb P\{A\ge m\}$ which is the probability that agent $A$ has at least $m$ amounts of money. For reals $n\le m$ it is clear that $\{A\ge m\}\subset\{A\ge n\}$ and therefore, we have the conditional probability
$$\tag{1}
\mathbb P\{A\ge m\,|A\ge n\}=\frac{\mathbb P\{A\ge m\}}{\mathbb P\{A\ge n\}}\,.
$$
In mathematics, the [Boltzmann-Gibbs distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) is called [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).
It is the one that leads to
$$
\mathbb P\{A\ge m\}=e^{-m/T}
$$
and
$$\tag{2}
\mathbb P\{A\ge m\,|A\ge n\}=\frac{\mathbb P\{A\ge m\}}{\mathbb P\{A\ge n\}}=
\mathbb P\{A\ge m-n\}=e^{-(m-n)/T}\,.
$$
This expression reflects the fact that money is conserved and additive. In other words, when we know that $A$ has at least $n$ then the probability to have at least $m$ is equal to the probability that unconditionally he has at least $m-n\,.$

Things to consider

- The Boltzmann-Gibbs distribution maximises the entropy (see link) which is why it is called equilibrium distribution.
- The constant $C=1/T$ corresponds to the intensity $\lambda$ in the exponential distribution.
- The expression $P(m)=P(m_1)P(m_2)$ should not be confused with the independence of the events that agent $1$ has $m_1$ and agent $2$ has $m_2\,.$

Comment: Thank you! What is $n$ here, the number of agents? I ask because your statement that "For reals ≤ it is clear that {≥}⊂{≥}" confuses me. How do you know that ≤ holds true? What if each agent has \$0.01 dollars? Wouldnt it be true that $m < n$, where n is number of agents and m is the total money in the group?

Comment: $n,m$ are real numbers. I did not want to use $m_1,m_2$ because we do not really need to consider a certain number of agents. one agent is enough I think.